# How do I publish a video compressed with h265?

Tags: server, video-streaming, rtmp, flv, hevc

I set up a nginx server and I can broadcast using rtmp. I do this by compressing it with h264, but I also need to compress it with h265. rtmp and flv do not support h265.
as a result can you offer me a server and protocol to use h265? get open source if possible.

edit:
okey should not explain the problem a little more. I can send a video to my nginx server with a client and watch this video in hls and dash.
But what I have to do is compress this video with a h265 applet with a converter like ffmpeg and then watch it or send it to another client. I couldn't find anything other than rtmp to send and receive videos.

Answer (score 1):

MP4 and MKV both support H.265 video streams.

You can use DASH or HLS to stream your MP4 segments.

Comment: actually i can do "dash" and "hls" broadcast. but these two players use the rtmp protocol. The rtmp protocol only works with flv, so it doesn't support h265. for example, this "ffmpeg" command does not work  `ffmpeg -i SHM_4818.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -f mp4 rtmp://localhost/src/hakan`  but it works if you write flv instead of mp4.

Comment: DASH and HLS have absolutely nothing to do with RTMP.

Comment: I am using nginx server "hls" and "dash" running in rtmp. I couldn't see a different example.  https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/